# How to get email from identityref

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I've looked at the `UserHttpClient`, `ProfileHttpClient` and `GraphHttpClient`.

I cannot figure out how I can retrieve the email address from any of those when I have an `IdentityRef` from a work item (the "AssignedTo" field).

Earlier I assumed that the `uniquename` field always where the email address, but that seems not to be the case for premise installations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

The `identityRef` contains a field called `Descriptor` which corresponds to the "user descriptor" in the `ProfileHttpClient` ([Rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)).

Thus, to get the email one have to do the following:

```cs
public static Task<string> GetEmailAddress(this VssConnection connection, SubjectDescriptor descriptor)
{
    var client = connection.GetClient<GraphHttpClient>();
    var user = await client.GetUserAsync(descriptor.ToString());
    return user?.MailAddress;
}

// .. and in your code (where assignedTo is an IdentityRef).
var email = await connection.GetEmailAddress(assignedTo.Descriptor);
```

**Update**

This doesn't work on Azure DevOps Server as the Graph is not available on it. So the question remains.

(Leaves this as an answer for the cloud version)

Comment: Similar to above, Is there a way to get other details from email
a. If i have email Id, is there a way to know if its valid email Id?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one way you can do this. You can get "id" from `IdentityRef` and do following rest Api call

> http://{server:port}/tfs/{collection)/_apis/identities/{identityId}?api-version=6.0

This will return **Identity** Object of type `Identity` (not IdentityRef). This object contains "properties" field, refer "Mail" property in this properties field, there you can find email.